Community Promotion Ads - 2015
As your site is undergoing our new design-independent graduation process, you'll be enjoying your own run of design-independent Community Promotion Ads! 
What are Community Promotion Ads?
Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.
Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

the site's twitter account 
relevant blogs and websites 
cryptography conferences, meetups, or other events 
anything else your community would genuinely be interested in 

The goal is for future visitors to find out about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own community's interests, both for those already in the community and those yet to join. 
Why do we reset the ads every year?
Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.
How does it work?
The answers you post to this question must conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored. 

All answers should be in the exact form of:
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url 

Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
The question must always be tagged with the magic community-ads tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

Image requirements

The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
Must be GIF or PNG
No animated GIFs
Absolute limit on file size of 40 KB
If the background of the image is white, there must be a 1x1 border of not-white at the edges of the ad

Score Threshold
There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.
You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats here.







PQ crypto be should promoted whenever possible :)



I think we indeed should promote this one for this year (to also promote the new Argon2). PHC will end this year with the final version of Argon2 so afterwards we may want to get rid off this.

Well, meanwhile argon2 has won the PHC.

Now that it's both winner and in its final form, I can upvote this. :)



This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting



Will they actually do anything besides that TrueCrypt audit?

@SEJPM, probably depends on funding.



Is the bear reference intentional or random?

@SEJPM, never recall paying any attention to any bears on security SE; if you google this, "bear crypto" is referenced as early as 1996 on the first page of the search results alone. :-)  But, hey, if the bear gets you there, feel free, and I'm all for it!

See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/crypto.stackexchange.com/bounty.png

This is an adoption of Community Promotion Ads - 2015 that will change if there are featured questions. The size is not a problem.




